# Shrink dataframe rows by matching element

Tags: r

I have a dataframe looking something like this:

```
  Name   Desc    Sex
1 John   young   M
2 Diana  young   F
3 Bob    old     M
4 Hanna  young   F
5 Ben    old     M
6 Liza   old     F
7 Ron    young   M
```

is there a way that i can group the rows in such a fashion that i end up with the following dataframe?

```
  Name          Desc   Sex
1 John, Ron     young  M
2 Diana, Hanna  young  F
3 Bob, Ben      old    M
4 Liza          old    F
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(text="Name   Desc    Sex
1 John   young   M
2 Diana  young   F
3 Bob    old     M
4 Hanna  young   F
5 Ben    old     M
6 Liza   old     F
7 Ron    young   M",h=T,strin=F)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr` we can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Desc,Sex) %>% summarise(Name=paste(Name,collapse = ','))

# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Desc [2]
  Desc  Sex   Name       
 <fct> <fct> <chr>      
1 old   F     Liza       
2 old   M     Bob,Ben    
3 young F     Diana,Hanna
4 young M     John,Ron
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `aggregate` in base `R`:

```
aggregate(Name ~ ., df, paste, collapse= ", ")
#    Desc Sex         Name
# 1   old   F         Liza
# 2 young   F Diana, Hanna
# 3   old   M     Bob, Ben
# 4 young   M    John, Ron
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Desc', 'Sex' `paste` the 'Name' together separated by `,`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Name = toString(Name)), by = .(Desc, Sex)]
#    Desc Sex         Name
#1: young   M    John, Ron
#2: young   F Diana, Hanna
#3:   old   M     Bob, Ben
#4:   old   F         Liza
```